# Logic verification: $x^3$ is irrational, then $x$ is also irrational

Tags: logic, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

Prove, by contraposition, if $x^3$ is irrational, then $x$ is also irrational.

Just a verification do I need to show that given $x$ is rational $x^3$ is also rational?

Suppose $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ than $x=\dfrac{p}{q}$, where $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $x^3=\dfrac{p\cdot p \cdot p}{q \cdot q \cdot q}=\dfrac{p^3}{q^3}$. Since the  product of\[6pt] two integers is a integer, We conclude $x^3 \in \mathbb{Q}$

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: It just seemed to easy so I wasn't sure

Comment: It would be good if you would write up an answer to the question yourself, perhaps even including a proof of the statement for completeness.

Comment: I've included the proof

Comment: I meant as an answer, so the question doesn't come up as unanswered.

Comment: Are you sure? In any case the question only comes up as unaswered if doesn't have any answer with positive score.

Comment: You can come back later to accept then. Good job.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ than $x=\dfrac{p}{q}$, where $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $x^3=\dfrac{p\cdot p \cdot p}{q \cdot q \cdot q}=\dfrac{p^3}{q^3}$. Since the  product of two integers is a integer, We conclude

$x^3 \in \mathbb{Q}$

Comment: Congratulations on your ability to copy the OP

Comment: He is the OP, though I don't see why he asked the question if he already knew the answer.

Comment: $\huge\text{L O L}$

Comment: You have a very big laugh my dear sir.

Comment: It was more of a question to verify if what I needed to prove was correct It seemed to easy.